# Should a function calling promise and not returning anything be considered an error?

Tags: javascript, testing, promise

I have a one method that looks like this:

```
doSomething(){
     return somethingPromisy().then((blerp) => {
         // do something with blerp
         return blerp;  // Modified, of course
     });
};
```

Then I have another method that looks like this:

```
doSomethingElse(){
    stepOne();
    var x = stepTwo();
    var y = stepThree(x);
    doSomething.then((data) => {
        stepFour(data + y);
    });
};
```

I'm using mocha+chai+sinon to test this code, in particular, `doSomethingElse`, and then I want to make some assertions - but how can I guarantee that the promise will be resolved by the time I make assertions? I know one option would be to change it to:

```
doSomethingElse(){
    /* ... */
    return doSomething.then(...);
};
```

If I do this, then it's pretty easy to write my test because then it's:

```
return doSomethingElse().then(() => {
    someFake.lastCall.args.should.deep.equal(expectedData);
});
```

In my test and everything is fine. But should I be returning the promise simply for the sake of returning the promise? I don't actually *care* about any kind of return value from `doSomethingElse` - I only care that when I'm testing that the function in `doSomething.then` was called, i.e. the `doSomething` promise has been resolved by the time I do my assertions.

So what's the "best" way to go about this?

Comment: Yes, about every function doing something asynchronous should return a promise for that. And not (just) because of the result value in the promise, but precisely for the reason that you can await it.

Comment: If your `doSomethingElse` function was so high-level that it is called by something that won't need to wait for it, and therefore does not pass the promise to its caller, it should have a `.catch()` handler at the end of the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be testing doSomething and doSomethingElse separately with doSomethingElse using a mock of doSomething, with a mocked then methd that can return your value for testing.  You basically want to test them separately not at the same time. You're basically coupling doSomething and doSomethingElse in this case which makes testing harder.  Testing should be easy, you aren't testing to see if promises work, so use a fake one to move on to testing logic!

I do not find a lack of return value to be an issue myself, there is a return value, you're just chaining it, not storing it.

Comment: In this particular case it's not necessarily that I'm calling `doSomething` - that the function exists is 100% irrelevant to this API. I *could* replace the function call with the code inside of it and my tests shouldn't have to change. That's why I don't want to mock this function, because the existence of the function is not something I want codified in my tests, just it's behavior.

Comment: @WayneWerner you're right, you could put the code directly in line and should be able to get the same result.  That's the point though.  You should be testing individually stepOne(), stepTwo(), stepThree(x), stepFour(data + y);  Once you have tests for those (or if you already do great!) you're basically just testing the sequencing, but why should that matter?  If the functions return the right values for the right inputs and tests can show that you ought not worry about testing sequencing like this. Especially since your example isn't returning anything, means you are good testing the pieces